# In express.js why no error when variable 'app' is used in its own definition?

Tags: javascript, express

In express.js, I’m having difficulty understanding why createApplication() does not throw an error, given that it uses app.handle(...) within an anonymous function which is defining that same variable ‘app’.

Tried to mimic this in jsFiddle, but got the ‘app is undefined’ error that I would expect. The function assignment expression beginning at the top of 
create Application() is what is troubling me:

```
function createApplication() {

  //New variable 'app' to be defined 
  //by anonymous function

    var app = function(req, res, next) {
      app.handle(req, res, next);        // But 'app' not fully defined yet!
  };

  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
  mixin(app, proto, false);

  // expose the prototype that will get set on requests
  app.request = Object.create(req, {
    app: {\ configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app         }
  })

  // expose the prototype that will get set on responses
  app.response = Object.create(res, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app 
    }})

  app.init();
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In JavaScript, `var` bindings are hoisted to the top of local or global scope containing the definition. Therefore, the variable has already been defined at the point the closure is created.
2. JS closures do not capture the values of bound variables when instantiated. Rather, free variables are directly bound to and thus references the lexical environment, thus the anonymous function sees the value of `app` when it is actually invoked.
3. The undefined variable error you encountered occurs at calls to `mixin`.

Comment: Thanks much, your 2nd point answers the question I had in mind.